# How do you display multiple JSON data in swiftUI

Tags: ios, json, swiftui

i would like to know how to access multiple json dates in swiftui.
my problem was that you should connect json data with each other

here is the first jason file:

```
 {
"place": "Mecca",
"type": "Makkiyah",
"count": 7,
"title": "Al-Fatiha",
"titleAr":"الفاتحة",
"index": "001",
"pages": "1",
"juz": [
    {
        "index": "01",
        "verse": {
            "start": "verse_1",
            "end": "verse_7"
        }
    }
]
},
{
"place": "Medina",
"type": "Madaniyah",
"count": 286,
"title": "Al-Baqara",
"titleAr":"البقرة",
"index": "002",
"pages": "2",
"juz": [
    {
        "index": "01",
        "verse": {
            "start": "verse_1",
            "end": "verse_141"
        }
    },
    {
        "index": "02",
        "verse": {
            "start": "verse_142",
            "end": "verse_252"
        }
    },
    {
        "index": "03",
        "verse": {
            "start": "verse_253",
            "end": "verse_286"
        }
    }
]
}
```

here is the second

```
{`{
"index": "001",
"name": "al-Fatihah",
"verse": {
    "verse_1": "﻿بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ",
    "verse_2": "ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَٰلَمِينَ",
    "verse_3": "ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ",
    "verse_4": "مَٰلِكِ يَوْمِ ٱلدِّينِ",
    "verse_5": "إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ",
    "verse_6": "ٱهْدِنَا ٱلصِّرَٰطَ ٱلْمُسْتَقِيمَ",
    "verse_7": "صِرَٰطَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ ٱلْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا ٱلضَّآلِّينَ"
},
"count": 7,
"juz": [
    {
        "index": "01",
        "verse": {
            "start": "verse_1",
            "end": "verse_7"
        }
    }
]
```

The third

```
{
    "index": "01",
    "start": {
        "index": "001",
        "verse": "verse_1",
        "name": "Al-Fatiha"
    },
    "end": {
        "index": "002",
        "verse": "verse_141",
        "name": "Al-Baqara"
    }
},
```

The Last one with Audio

```
{
"index": "001",
"verse": {
    "verse_1": {
        "file": "001.mp3",
        "size": 27426,
        "unit": "26,78 KB"
    },
    "verse_2": {
        "file": "002.mp3",
        "size": 26773,
        "unit": "26,15 KB"
    },
    "verse_3": {
        "file": "003.mp3",
        "size": 21809,
        "unit": "21,3 KB"
    },
    "verse_4": {
        "file": "004.mp3",
        "size": 17761,
        "unit": "17,34 KB"
    },
    "verse_5": {
        "file": "005.mp3",
        "size": 25075,
        "unit": "24,49 KB"
    },
    "verse_6": {
        "file": "006.mp3",
        "size": 23377,
        "unit": "22,83 KB"
    },
    "verse_7": {
        "file": "007.mp3",
        "size": 63736,
        "unit": "62,24 KB"
    }
},
"count": 7
```

}

I hope you can help me.
the whole thing should end up like a book and audio player.
I tried it alone and only called the first json in foreach, how does the rest of the json file go?
the whole thing should end up like a book and audio player.
I hope for your help.
I Love SwiftUI
thank you in advance

Comment: Your json is incorrect, can you add correct json again

Comment: I get the json from hier I hope this is better. https://github.com/semarketir/quranjson.git.

Comment: How do you want to show the data? Do you have any UX or structure in mind?

Comment: struct Surah: Codable, Identifiable {
    struct Juz: Codable {
        let index: String
        let verse: Verse
    }
    struct Verse: Codable, Hashable {
        let start, end: String
    }
    enum Place: String, Codable {
        case mecca = "Mecca"
        case medina = "Medina"
    }
    enum TypeEnum: String, Codable {
        case madaniyah = "Madaniyah"
        case makkiyah = "Makkiyah"
    }
 
    let place: Place
    let type: TypeEnum
    let count: Int
    let title, titleAr, index, pages: String
    let id : String
    let juz: [Juz]
}

Comment: this was the beginning only und i don#t now how can I call the second part

Comment: struct ContentView: View {

    let surahs: [Surah] = Bundle.main.decode("source/surah.json")
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(surahs){section in
                    Section(header:Text(section.title)){
                        ForEach(section.juz, id: \.verse){juzs in
                            Text(juzs.verse.start)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
              
               }
        }
        
    }
}